# повторный вызов сканера

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы

что нужно записать в условии if что б сканер вызывался до окончания заполнения всех ячеек в матрице?

int [][]array= new int[5][5];

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введіть число щоб заповнити масив: ");
    int num = in.nextInt();

    if (???) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < 5; j++)
                array[i][j] = num;
        }

        System.out.println("The array 5x5: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                System.out.println(array[i][j] + " "); //виведення масиву
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Не нужно дублировать вопросы, в которых вы не понимаете проблему и не можете ее объяснить. Такие вопросы непредставляют интереса и бесполезны для пользователей. Потрудитесь сами написать код, чтобы понять в чем проблемы.

Comment: А зачем там что-то писать?  Вы заполняете весь массив одним числом?

Comment: [Вот](http://study-java.ru/uroki-java/urok-12-mnogomerny-e-massivy-v-java/) ресурс для обучения.

Comment: @RomanC, там не показано как использовать сканер для заполнения :)
A [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67152404/create-matrix-using-scanner-enter-row-by-row-in-java) показано

Comment: @AlexRudenko Это ссылка на английскую версию стэковерофлоу.

Comment: @AlexRudenko разними

Comment: @bis, напишите уже `array[i][j] = in.nextInt();`

Comment: @RomanC, а разве запрещены ссылки на англоязычные ресурсы?

Comment: @AlexRudenko нет, но для этого надо знать английский,чтобы понять. Потом правило использования ссылки в ответе не менялось и поэтому содержимое ссылки надо переводить.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто добавить сканер в цикл.

```
    int[][]array=new int[3][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++){ Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введіть число щоб заповнити масив: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();
            array[i][j] = num;
    }}


    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " "); //виведення масиву
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]